# Creating an electricity/lighting/tesla coil effect in a 2D XNA game?

Tags: 2d, graphics-programming, xna-4.0, graphic-effects

I'd like to create beams of electricity between two points very similar to this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eMJ8-56L3Lc. The effect is so dynamic, with varying lengths and pseudo-random movement in-between the points, that I'm having trouble imagining how I'd accomplish such a thing. Is there any helpful information that might point me in the right direction?

I should note that I'm using the XNA 4.0 Reach profile, but custom shaders are okay because I'm not targeting the Windows Phone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.catalinzima.com/samples/12-months-12-samples-2008/lightning-sample/

and for XNA 4.0:
http://www.hatchingdisaster.com/LightningSampleXNA4.zip

Comment: This is even closer to what I was looking for, so I'm moving the accepted answer to here.

Answer (score 16):

My friend is working on a side-scrolling shooter in XNA that uses similar effects ([here's a video of an early test](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NE8Zq4whs_A&feature=player_embedded)). He wrote [a blog post about the technique](http://drilian.com/2009/02/25/lightning-bolts/) that you might find helpful.

He's also usually hanging out in the #graphicschat IRC channel on irc.afternet.org (name's Drilian) and could probably help you out.

Comment: That is an excellent blog post; thank you! Exactly what I was looking for!