# Electricity effect using XNA and Shaders

Tags: xna, hlsl, effects

I'm looking for a shader or sample that does an electricity or lines-of-force effect between two points that can be used with XNA 3.1.

Comment: You might be interested [in this question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/7569/creating-an-electricity-lighting-tesla-coil-effect-in-a-2d-xna-game), which provides an interesting method for producing lightning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download RenderMonkey has samples for image based effects including spark and electricity.

Comment: I downloaded RenderMonkey. Really nice and lots of cool effects but no spark and no electricity sample.

Comment: I think you can find it in an example called "image space effects" .. its not the default shader by so you need to browse different shaders in the example.

Comment: Got it, thanks. That is just what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure if this fits to your picture of "electricity effect":
[video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5UMOXGPdWe4) and [article about it](http://drilian.com/2009/02/25/lightning-bolts/)

Comment: Your video link is broken.