# How can I implement beam effects like these?

Tags: opengl, particles

I am interested in the techniques I could use to create the following effects:

[image]

Can I accomplish this with a particle system or a series of texture quads, or what?

You can see this effects in action here in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=MDi9hjTfRPA#t=828).

Comment: You may find [this post](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/71397/how-can-i-generate-a-lightning-bolt-effect) and [this post](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/7569/creating-an-electricity-lighting-tesla-coil-effect-in-a-2d-xna-game) relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think *Polyboards* would be the thing for you. If you can get yourself a copy of [Mathematics for 3D Game Programming and Computer Graphics](http://www.mathfor3dgameprogramming.com/), there is a section dedicated to this technique in the book.

Comment: Here's a link in Google Books: http://books.google.ca/books?id=cZ0LAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA258 

In other contexts I've seen this approach called a "LineRenderer" or "TrailRender" (Unity)

Comment: The relevant polyboard algorithm is visible at least. Thanks @DMGregory

Comment: thank you for the link, do you think all effects are created with the same technique and just have different textures applied or is number 3 just done with particles?

Comment: I am not sure others would approve but I think you should focus on a specific energy beam cause otherwise you might only get very shallow answers that don't explain anything in detail.

Comment: It looks to me like the small circular elements, hexagons, and explosions/flares in 3 & 4 are done with regular particles, while all of the beam effects are done with a polygon strip. The green snot stream could be either, or a combination.

Comment: I agree with @DMGregory, It seems like the effects on No3 are standard particles renderer with camera-facing billboards.